# CUIT fails on other machines

Tags: visual-studio, testing, user-interface, automated-tests, coded-ui-tests

14 hours and couldn't find out WHY ???

I've done some tests for a web application and all of them are running perfectly, till I started running the tests on 3 different machines all of them failed but still working on my dev machine

most of the tests are done manually, I only used the test builder to generate the UI Map

I used this walkthrough to use multiple UI Maps and to do most of the tests manually
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/anutthara/archive/2010/02/10/walkthrough-using-multiple-coded-ui-maps-in-test-automation.aspx

How I'm generating the Map,
- create new map
- run the test builder for this map
- do some assertions on all the controls that i need in the test
- generate the method
- then delete the generated method from the map, because i dont need it, and to get all the controls in the map

Then i'm using the same way in the walkthrough to code the test steps

I repeated these steps again on one of the maps, after i got that problem and that solved the problem, but because I've done all tests manually this will take me days to change all the controls names in all the maps

I checked the Designer.cs for the map very carefully to find any changes between the old and the new ones, but nothing different, 
I made sure that searchproperties and searchconfigurations are not using something like window title and these stuff.
I'm relying on Id, Name, TagInstance which are all the same

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue recently with Coded UIs.

The tests run fine on my machine with VS 2013 that has 8 GB of RAM, but seem to constantly fail on the rest of the machines that have 4 GB RAM.

For a quick fix I added the following to my test methods:

```
Playback.PlaybackSettings.WaitForReadyLevel = WaitForReadyLevel.AllThreads;
```

Later on I went through the failure points and adjusted to the conditions & in some cases added a 1 or 2 second wait (even though I hate doing it) to allow the page or object to fully.